# Часть предложения слова "в потолке"

Tags: члены-предложения

Он не заметил сучка в потолке.

Можно ли определить "в потолке" как обстоятельство места? В таком случае слово будет определимо как обстоятельство, дополнение и определение? Бывает, что слово совмещает в себе функции трех членов предложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. Это действительно синкретичный член предложения, совмещающий функции обстоятельства(не заметил где?), дополнения(сучка в чём?) и определения(сучка какого?). Только на первом месте я бы поставила несогласованное определение, оно стоит сразу за дополнением и распространяет его. Вот если бы было *Он не заметил  в потолке сучка*. - основной функцией было бы обстоятельство.